# Тире, двоеточие или запятая? У кого ты украл деньги () у отца или у матери?

Tags: пунктуация

*У кого ты украл деньги () у отца или у матери?* Какой знак препинания здесь нужен?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Возможны три варианта:** (1) У кОго ты украл деньги — у отца или у матери? (2) У кОго ты украл дЕньги: у отца или у матери? (3)У кОго ты украл дЕньги, у отца или у матери? Чаще встречается первый вариант (в этом случае **ударение падает на вопросительное  местоимение**).

**Пояснение**

Для решения надо определить вид грамматической конструкции. С одной стороны, это однородные члены и обобщающее слово, с другой — однородные члены связаны одиночным союзом  ИЛИ и образуют единую фразу, и тогда это тема пояснительных членов предложения.

У Розенталя:  "Если однородные члены предложения носят характер приложения или уточнения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия может ставиться тире: Легенды и сказки любят все — дети и взрослые".  **Итак, можно ставить двоеточие или тире,** которые в устной речи обозначаются подчеркнутой паузой.  Но структура подобных предложений допускает произношение и  **без паузы**, и поэтому возможно **обособление запятой**, что мы и видим на практике.

**Примеры похожих предложений с вопросительным словом:**

Ты кого больше любишь: девиц или дам? [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Приваловские миллионы (1883)]

А ты кого больше любил ― отца или мать? [Вальтер Запашный. Риск. Борьба. Любовь (1998-2004)]

Павлик, ты кого больше любишь, маму или бабу? [Л. С. Петрушевская. Три девушки в голубом (1980)]

Да ты кого больше любишь, меня или Лиду? [В. Ф. Панова. Спутники (1945)]

Answer (score 1):

Пояснительные члены предложения выделяются запятыми, но при наличии слов, обязательно требующих раскрытия (пояснения) значения, ставится тире (здесь это слово *кого*). Можно вставить "а именно". Здесь же очень похоже на уточнение - особенно по смыслу, но и в таком случае при подчеркивании смысла стоит отделить "у отца или у матери" от уточняемого слова, воспользовавшись тире.